# How do you remove ambiguity from "Examined the impact of doing something while doing something else"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is there a potential ambiguity in the following sentence? I know that the *sentence structure* can be ambiguous under a different context, but what about the sentence itself?

> **Main sentence:** Examined the fiscal and economic impacts of regionally differentiating EI benefits while keeping premiums equal across all regions.

Here is a different example to show where the ambiguity is:

> [The researcher] examined the fiscal and economic impacts of regionally differentiating EI benefits ***while taking into account the labour force size of each region.***

In the above sentence, the part ***"while taking into ..."*** is adding information about the researcher.

The situation is made worse by the omission of the subjects in the main sentence:

> **Main sentence:** Examined the fiscal and economic impacts of [the program] regionally differentiating EI benefits while [it was] keeping premiums equal across all regions.

The best I could come up with to remove the potential ambiguity is to add a subject to the main sentence.

> **Main sentence:** Examined the fiscal and economic impacts of **the program** regionally differentiating EI benefits while keeping premiums equal across all regions.

But now it sounds kind of weird. We usually don't include the subject "the government" in a sentence like this:

> The paper examines the fiscal and economic impacts of [the government] increasing the minimum wage.

---

How can I remove the ambiguity from the main sentence while ensuring that it doesn't sound too weird?

Comment: I don’t see any real ambiguity there that can’t be resolved with context. “Examined impacts of equal premiums for regionally differentiated benefits.” seems like the only sensible interpretation to me. Human readers resolve ambiguities in single sentences by considering the context before deciding exactly what it must mean. This looks like a resume sentence to me, so most people aren’t going to care about the precise details until they can ask you more about it in an interview.

Comment: @ColleenV I see. Is this any better: *"Examined the fiscal and economic impacts of regionally differentiated benefits but equal premium rates"*?

Comment: Honestly, without more context I can’t say. I think it’s probably fine the way you’ve written it, and that you should set it aside for a couple days and come back to it. I think this may be one of those cases where the more you focus on it, the weirder it looks. You aren’t writing a contract where someone might argue about that ambiguity, so have some faith that your readers will be able to figure it out well enough to understand what they need to know. Unless you’re writing for a computer algorithm… they can be pretty dumb.